# Set enviroment variables in Heroku from .env file

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I'm developing a Node application using Docker and docker-compose, which all have awesome ways to import multiple environment variables from a `.env` file.

Just wondering if there's a shortcut for updating a Heroku deployment's env vars instead of typing them out.

I've noticed there's no `--env-file` option on the official docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using some `xargs` magic

```sh
cat .env.prod | xargs heroku config:set

# Output:
# API_PORT:       3000
# API_KEY_1:      ab-cd
# DB_PORT:        6379
# REDISCLOUD_URL: xxx
```

Happily sets multiple args from a local .env file