# Next js and Heruko config vars not working

Tags: heroku, next.js, environment-variables, production

I have a next js app with an .env.production file. In the file i have an Api key variable:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV_LOCAL_API_KEY=process.env.API_KEY

On the left is the next var, which i can access local, right is the config var from Heruko. 

This is my .env.local, it works local
```

NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV_LOCAL_INFURA_API_KEY="0000011111122222233333"

What is the problem, does Heruko need any further config?

Tried setting different typings for the .env.production file

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66184811/set-enviroment-variables-in-heroku-from-env-file

Answer (score 0):

Ended up setting the vars direct without the .env file. Worked like expected.